# linear-gradient (as background) not working on chrome (android)

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, linear-gradients

I've the following property for background in my css.

```
background: linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(56, 114, 169, 1) 0%, rgba(16, 36, 57, 1) 58%);
```

The web page that I am trying to view is https://dg2-dev-eu-dg2-web-user-portal.apps-dev.chdc20-cf.solera.com/privacy?app=dg&v=1.0.0&lang=en.

It renders perfectly in Firefox on android, but doesn't work on Chrome. Can someone give me a clue as to what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Just realised that it works if the phone is in landscape orientation, but doesn't work in portrait ...

Comment: Have you ever tried to use webkit ? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions

Comment: Also, which version of Android and on what device?

Comment: Yes, adding the webkit prefix doesn't help. Android 8, Chrome 74, Sony Xperia XZs. The same issue was reported from a couple of other devices as well.

Comment: what if you remove background-attachment:fixed?

Comment: That doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser compatibility is an issue when using gradients so you have to include compatibility for all browsers hope this will help

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>123</title>
</head>

<body style="
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(56, 114, 169, 1) 0%, rgba(16, 36, 57, 1) 58%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(56, 114, 169, 1) 0%, rgba(16, 36, 57, 1) 58%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(56, 114, 169, 1) 0%, rgba(16, 36, 57, 1) 58%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(56, 114, 169, 1) 0%, rgba(16, 36, 57, 1) 58%);">

</body>
</html>
```

here Webkit is for chrome, moz is for Mozilla ,o for Opera, ms for MS Explorer

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't help.